# Find value in nested tag with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the price value from a block of html that looks like this:

```
<div class="price">
  <span>
    <span class=""><span class="value"></span></span>
    <span class=" list">
      <span class="value">$129.99</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I tried `price = soup.find("span", {"class": "value"}).contents[1]` thinking that would give me the contents of the second `span` with a class of `value` however I get an error saying `list index out of range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
price = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "value"})[1].text
```

Answer (score 2):

`soup.find` returns the FIRST matching item.  You're thinking of `find_all`.  Or, you could use an XPATH expression like `div/span/span[2]/span`.

Answer (score 1):

Inner span with `class='value'` is not really children of the first span, so `.contents`[[docs]](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) will not give you desired value. If you want to grab content from upper span tag for some reason, you can use `.find_next()` to move on to the next tag and grab its content:

```
price = soup.find("span", {"class": "value"}).find_next().get_text().strip()
# '$129.99'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
soup.find("span", {"class": "list"}).find("span", {"class": "value"}).text
```